# Cloud9 local workspace location

Tags: cloud9-ide

How can I set the cloud9 workspace directory, right now it defaults to the directory of cloud9 itself, which is `~/local/cloud9`.

I tried editing config.js in the root like:

```
exports.Config = {
    workspace: "/var/www",
    ip: "127.0.0.1",
    port: 3000,
    gaeLocalPath: "/var/www",
};
```

Both those vars were `"."` before, i set them to the `"/var/www"`, which I want as the default location.

But as you've guessed, it won't work. Tried restarting etc.

I'v searched for other settings files, but nothing.

I kindof like this editor, but I don't want my FTP setting in the 'c9 cloud', and it's local data for my own website, so why bother with FTP?

Or does anyone recommend a better alternative, a webeditor, with code syntax highlighting? And local file support?

Comment: Which version of cloud9 do you use? with https://github.com/c9/core you can pass `-w /var/www` argument from command line when launching cloud9.

Comment: it worked for me.